# Improve efficiency of lookup algorithm in R

Tags: r

I think this is an interesting task to optimize a piece of R code.

I have a dataframe `df_red` which details from orders of a webshop. For each product (ean), I want to get the 12 most likely other products to be in a basket with it.

This is the sample code to generate such data set:

```
library(tidyverse)

# create a vector with 1400 products (characterized by their EANs)
eans <- sample(1e5:1e6, 1400, replace = FALSE)
# create a vector with 200k orders 
basket_nr <- 1:2e5

# a basket can have up to 4 items, it's most likely to have 3 items
n_prod_per_basket <- sample(x = 1:4, length(basket_nr), prob = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.1), replace = TRUE)

# create df_red, each line of which correspond to a product with it's respective basket number
df <- data_frame(basket_nr, n_prod_per_basket)

df_red <- data_frame(basket_nr = rep(basket_nr, n_prod_per_basket))
df_red$ean <- sample(x = eans, nrow(df_red), replace = TRUE)
```

The code I am using to accomplish this task is the following. But I am sure it's not an efficient one. How can I increase the speed of the program?

```
ean <- unique(df_red$ean)

out <- list()

for (i in 1:length(ean)){

ean1 <- ean[i]
# get all basket_nr that contain the ean in question
basket_nr <- df_red[df_red$ean == ean1, ]$basket_nr

# get products that were together in the same basket with the ean in question
boo <- (df_red$ean != ean1) & (df_red$basket_nr %in% basket_nr)
prod <- df_red[boo, ]

# get top most frequent
top12 <- prod %>% 
group_by(ean) %>% 
summarise(n = n()) %>% 
arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
filter(row_number() %in% 1:12)

# skip products that weren't together in a basket with at least 12 different other products
if(nrow(top12) == 12) out[[i]] <- data_frame(ean = ean1, recom = top12$ean, freq = top12$n)

if(i %% 100 == 0) print(paste0(round(i/length(ean)*100, 2), '% is complete'))

}
```

Comment: This sounds like a classic market basket analysis example.  You might want to check out the `arules` package.  I have not used it but I believe it was design for applications such as this.

Comment: I think this could be written as a (slightly complex) SQL query.  If so, the [sqldf](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf) package should have nice performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance improvements are of course a matter of degree. How far to go before it is improved "enough" is hard to say. However, we can reduce run time by about 25% by functionalizing your code and cleaning up the subsetting logic. Starting with your code:

```
#added a timer
start.time <- Sys.time()
for (i in 1:length(ean)){

  ean1 <- ean[i]
  # get all basket_nr that contain the ean in question
  basket_nr <- df_red[df_red$ean == ean1, ]$basket_nr

  # get products that were together in the same basket with the ean in question
  boo <- (df_red$ean != ean1) & (df_red$basket_nr %in% basket_nr)
  prod <- df_red[boo, ]

  # get top most frequent
  top12 <- prod %>% 
    group_by(ean) %>% 
    summarise(n = n()) %>% 
    arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
    filter(row_number() %in% 1:12)

  # skip products that weren't together in a basket with at least 12 different other products
  if(nrow(top12) == 12) out[[i]] <- data_frame(ean = ean1, recom = top12$ean, freq = top12$n)

  if(i %% 100 == 0) print(paste0(round(i/length(ean)*100, 2), '% is complete'))

}
Sys.time() - start.time
```

This takes between 30-34 seconds on my machine. However we can rewrite it as a function like so:

```
my.top12.func <- function(id, df_red) {
  #improved subsetting logic - using which is faster and we can remove some code by
  #removing the ean that is being iterated in the filter step below
  prod <- df_red[df_red$basket_nr %in% df_red$basket_nr[which(df_red$ean == id)], ]

  # set cutoff from 12 to 13 since the specific ean will always be one of the top 12
  top12 <- prod %>% 
    group_by(ean) %>% 
    summarise(n = n()) %>% 
    arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
    filter(row_number() %in% 1:13 & ean != id) #additional filter required

  # skip products that weren't together in a basket with at least 12 different other products
  if(nrow(top12) == 12) return(data_frame(ean = id, recom = top12$ean, freq = top12$n))
}
```

Now we can test the speed and accuracy of this approach by doing:

```
start.time <- Sys.time()
my.out <- lapply(ean, my.top12.func, df_red = df_red)
Sys.time() - start.time

#test for equality
all.equal(out, my.out)
```

Which is about 24-26 seconds for a 25%+ improvement.

Comment: Replacing `lapply()` with the new-ish `purrr::map_dfr()` will produce one large dataframe, instead of a list with three smaller data frames.

Answer (score 2):

Playing around with `data.table` I have the output produced in under 7 seconds (which I guess is about 80% improvement):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df_red)
all_eans <- df_red[, unique(ean)]
k <- lapply(all_eans, function(x) {
    df_red[basket_nr %in% df_red[ean == x, unique(basket_nr)],
           .N, 
           by = ean][order(-N)][2:13]
  }
)
names(k) <- all_eans
k <- k[sapply(k, nrow) == 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider not using a loop.

```
df_red$k <- 1
df_s     <- left_join(df_red, df_red, by = "k") %>%
            filter(ean.x != ean.y & basket_nr.x == basket_nr.y) %>%
            group_by(ean.x) %>%
            summarise(n = n()) %>%
            arrange(desc(n)) %>%
            filter(row_number() %in% 1:13) 

df_s.ct  <- df_s %>% filter(row_number() == 12)
df_s.fin <- df_s[df_s$ean.x %in% df_s.ct$ean.x, ]
```

The rate limiting step in this is the `left_join` which merges the dataset to itself, creating an exponentially larger dataset (so if you have 50,000 points, then you will end up creating a new dataset that is 2.5B points). It now indicates that the best way to store and manipulate the data is using `data.table`, which will increase the speed of this procedure, especially when combined with `dplyr`.